# Google charts draw() performance

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to build an application which, among other things, draws several Google Charts Timelines. The data used to populate the timelines is pulled from JSON files, some quite large. The largest of my test data is around 30MB.

The Google Charts documentation says that `chart.draw(table, options)` is asynchronous. However, that does not appear to be the case. When I load in my data and start drawing the charts, my app locks up until the last chart completes its drawing process.

```javascript
// several times, call:
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline'],
  callback: this.layoutTimelineFor_(
    container,
    this.data[group],
    group),
  });

// ...

layoutTimelineFor_: function(container, timeline, group) {
  return () => {
    const chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    const table = this.mapTimelineToDataTable_(timeline, group);

    // ...

    const options = {
      backgroundColor: 'transparent',
      height: document.documentDelement.clientHeight / 2 - 50,
      width: (container.parentElement || container)
        .getBoundingClientRect().width,
      forceIFrame: true,
      timeline: {
        singleColor: '#d5ddf6',
      },
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'none',
      },
      hAxis: {
        minValue: 0,
      },
    };

    if (this.duration > 0) {
      options.hAxis.format = this.pickTimeFormat_(this.duration);
      options.hAxis.maxValue = this.duration;
      const p1 = performance.now();
      chart.draw(table, options);
      const p2 = performance.now();
      console.log(`${group} chart.draw(table, options) took ${p2-p1}ms`);
    } else {
      this.chartQueue_.push({chart, table, options, group});
    }
  }
}

// ...

durationChanged: function() {
  while (this.chartQueue_.length) {
    const data = this.chartQueue_.shift();
    data.options.hAxis.format = this.pickTimeFormat_(this.duration);
    data.options.hAxis.maxValue = this.duration;
    const p1 = performance.now();
    data.chart.draw(data.table, data.options);
    const p2 = performance.now();
    console.log(`${data.group} chart.draw(table, options) took ${p2-p1}ms`);
  }
}
```

The output of my two timers is something along these lines:

```
label chart.draw(table, options) took 154.26999999999998ms
shot chart.draw(table, options) took 141.98500000000013ms
face chart.draw(table, options) took 1601.9849999999997ms
person chart.draw(table, options) took 13932.140000000001ms
```

These numbers are roughly proportional to the size of the JSON being used as data for each Timeline chart. (Note: the above numbers come from ~20MB of test data, not my largest.)

Locking up my application for 296ms would be unfortunate, but acceptable. Heck, most users probably won't notice a 1.9s delay, either. 15.8s is unacceptable. And yet, [Google's guide](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_draw_chart) says:

> The `draw()` method is asynchronous: that is, it returns immediately, but the instance that it returns might not be immediately available.

Is there a way I can get `draw` to run asynchronously, like the documentation claims it should be?

Comment: Just asking, `~20MB` of data, wouldn't that be a bit too precise for a simple statistical chart? Perhaps you should narrow down the time window or the cut the precision from 1 second to 2 seconds, would make it 50% smaller, making it render 50% faster. Either way, `async` calls still heavily rely on the browsers implantation. Chrome vs Firefox would both display other results.

Comment: @WhiteHat, thanks. I think I was calling it just once in a previous version of the code. Switching back to a single load() call does not solve the problem, however.

Comment: @Xorifelse, the data is corresponding to a video being displayed elsewhere on the page. The largest JSON files were generated based on the video running at 10fps. The 13932.14ms number above is coming from a file with the general structure of `{"id":"4574491","annotations":{"person":[...26661 Objects]}}`

Comment: @WhiteHat, won't that just force the Timelines to be drawn in sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research, it appears that only the actual *drawing* of the chart is asynchronous. Before the drawing begins, the data goes through a (synchronous) processing step, which is the cause of my issue. There is no solution for the Timeline chart with a dataset as large as mine.

Core charts (Area, Bar, Bubble, Candlestick, Column, Combo, Histogram, Line, Pie, Scatter, and Stepped Area) have an `allowAsync` option [as of version 41](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes#february-23-2015) which breaks up this processing step into chunks so that the whole process can be interrupted (although each chunk can't). Timeline is, unfortunately, not a core chart, and does not have this option.